# shared dynamic_reconfigure_servers in different nodes

Tags: ros, rosgraph, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to have two different nodes with an dynamic_reconfigure::Server sharing the same "resource name" in the rosgraph context?
This would be interesting to share configurations between different nodes. If someone send a config update request, then both nodes would be configured simultaneusly.

```
Node1.cpp for process 1:
---
dynamic_reconfigure::Server server1(ros::NodeHandle("/shared/name"));
server1.setCallback(myP1Callback);
...

Node2.cpp for process 2:
---
dynamic_reconfigure::Server server2(ros::NodeHandle("/shared/name"));
server2.setCallback(myP2Callback);
...
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50502/shared-dynamic_reconfigure_servers-in-different-nodes/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2012-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think so.

They would both have to declare the same ROS service.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2012-12-14**:
I had just tested it. It doesn't work. As you say they both shares a service named "set_update" (a point-to-point operation). One interesting point its that everything looks work,but only one receives the updates. In the end I'll have to use topics. I think this would be a desirable feature.